# Testing NSFileProtectionComplete in iOS simulator and device

Tags: ios4, encryption, ios-simulator, ios5

I have this code written for my - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator in a coreData app. I used xCode's Master-Detail Application template to create the app...

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes2.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    NSString *urlString = [storeURL absoluteString];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:urlString error:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle error
    }


    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

How can I test and know that my sqlite has NSFileProtectionComplete turned on?

I locked the simulator, but the file was still readable when i double clicked on the file in Finder.

Comment: I also tested it on a device by locking the device then using iTunes and the iTunes File Sharing to copy the file from the device to my desktop...but the file was still readable.

Comment: Were you able to test this?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes won't copy files from the device unless it has your passcode or the device has previously been trusted; that's how it is able to decrypt the data.

In Xcode 8 and earlier the Simulator uses the host filesystem and macOS does not currently support per-file encryption the same way iOS does, so on macOS you cannot test this in the Simulator.